# How can I resolve a  "dim screen" issue on both on board and nvidia graphics?

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, display, multiple-monitors

My new laptop has Intel HD integrated video and an Nvidia card. Both drivers are enabled according to the device manager. Should I disable the integrated video or leave both running? I'm having the 'dim screen' problem in Windows 7 on a separate monitor. Nvidia detects the 2nd screen correctly and the Intel driver doesn't. Modifying the power options doesn't have any effect.

It's a Lenovo t520 running 64 bit Windows 7. The monitor is dvi connected thru the docking station. The Nvidia card sees it & the Intel integrated graphics doesn't.

Comment: More information about the laptop you are using would be helpful: model, OS, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would disable the on board graphics. Having them both running is not worth it. Choose one and disable the other one.